# React.js output shows as NaN

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hi as stated above my output keeps showing up as NaN and I'm really struggling to fix it.

There are ultimately three classes that will touch the code. App.js, Calculate.js, and Calculations.js where all of the functions are stored. In Calculate.js, I am importing two functions from Calculations.js with the hopes of producing their output after data is taken in from four input fields and a button press. The code for all three files is below.Please help, I truly am lost now.

Edit: it should be noted the calculations were given to us and are basically unmodifiable.
App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Calculate from './components/Calculate';
import Clear from './components/Clear';

//need to put clear underneath Calculate
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text> 'Please enter your coordinates you wish to calculate.' </Text>
      <Calculate buttonTitle = 'Calculate'/>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Calculate.js

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput} from 'react-native';
import {Button} from 'react-native-elements';
import {computeDistance, computeBearing} from './Calculations';

const Calculate = ({buttonTitle, lat1, lon1, lat2,lon2, distance, bearing}) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({lat1: '', lon1: '', lat2: '', lon2: '', distance: '', bearing: ''});

    const updateStateObject = (vals) =>{
        setState({
            ...state,
            ...vals,
        });
    };
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput 
                placeholder = 'Starting latitude' 
                onChangeText = {(lat1) => updateStateObject({lat1: lat1})} //or you could do (val) => {setName(val);}
                value = {state.lat1}/>
            <TextInput 
                placeholder = 'Starting longitude' 
                onChangeText = {(lon1) => updateStateObject({lon1: lon1})} //or you could do (val) => {setName(val);}
                value = {state.lon1}/>
            <TextInput 
                placeholder = 'Ending latitude' 
                onChangeText = {(lat2) => updateStateObject({lat2: lat2})} //or you could do (val) => {setName(val);}
                value = {state.lat2}/>
            <TextInput 
                placeholder = 'Ending longitude' 
                onChangeText = {(lon2) => updateStateObject({lon2: lon2})} //or you could do (val) => {setName(val);}
                value = {state.lon2}/>
            <Button 
            title= {buttonTitle}
            onPress = {() =>{
                state.distance = computeDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2);
                state.bearing = computeBearing(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2);
                updateStateObject({distance: `Distance: ${distance}`});
                updateStateObject({bearing: `Bearing: ${bearing}`});
            }} />
            <Text> {state.distance}</Text>
            <Text> {state.bearing}</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
  });
export default Calculate;
```

Calculations.js

```
 // Converts from degrees to radians.
 function toRadians(degrees) {
    return (degrees * Math.PI) / 180;
  }

  // Converts from radians to degrees.
  function toDegrees(radians) {
    return (radians * 180) / Math.PI;
  }

  // Computes distance between two geo coordinates in kilometers.
  export function computeDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    console.log(`p1={${lat1},${lon1}} p2={${lat2},${lon2}}`);
    var R = 6371; // km (change this constant to get miles)
    var dLat = ((lat2 - lat1) * Math.PI) / 180;
    var dLon = ((lon2 - lon1) * Math.PI) / 180;
    var a =
      Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
      Math.cos((lat1 * Math.PI) / 180) *
        Math.cos((lat2 * Math.PI) / 180) *
        Math.sin(dLon / 2) *
        Math.sin(dLon / 2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    var d = R * c;
    return `${round(d, 3)} km`;
  }

  // Computes bearing between two geo coordinates in degrees.
 export function computeBearing(startLat, startLng, destLat, destLng) {
    startLat = toRadians(startLat);
    startLng = toRadians(startLng);
    destLat = toRadians(destLat);
    destLng = toRadians(destLng);

    var y = Math.sin(destLng - startLng) * Math.cos(destLat);
    var x =
      Math.cos(startLat) * Math.sin(destLat) -
      Math.sin(startLat) * Math.cos(destLat) * Math.cos(destLng - startLng);
    var brng = Math.atan2(y, x);
    brng = toDegrees(brng);
    return (brng + 360) % 360;
  }

  function round(value, decimals) {
    return Number(Math.round(value + "e" + decimals) + "e-" + decimals);
  }
```

Output
[image]

Comment: You should convert the coordinates (lat...lon) to numbers first. Use parseFloat(lat1) and so on, on all of them before doing any computation.

Comment: like this?: `            <TextInput 
                placeholder = 'Starting latitude' 
                onChangeText = {(lat1) => updateStateObject({lat1: parseFloat(lat1)})} //or you could do (val) => {setName(val);}
                value = {state.lat1}/>`

Comment: Rather do it here so the TextInput will still be bound to a string


export function computeDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {  lat1 = parseFloat(lat1)
    ...

Comment: unfortunately due to the nature of the assignment, the calculations file itself is pretty much copy and paste and we have to work off of that without modifying it really. I appreciate the help though.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently I have had a misunderstanding on what state is and how it is used. The working button should read as the following:

```
<Button 
   title={buttonTitle}
   onPress = {() =>{updateStateObject({
        distance: `Distance: ${computeDistance( parseFloat(lat1),  parseFloat(lon1),  parseFloat(lat2),  parseFloat(lon2))}`,
        bearing: `Bearing: ${computeBearing( parseFloat(lat1),  parseFloat(lon1),  parseFloat(lat2),  parseFloat(lon2))}`,
        })
    }}
/>
```

Comment: then parse it here